# Angular 8 - Typescript > ERROR TypeError: array.find is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I am getting **array.find is not a function** error in the below code:

```js
findWhere(array, criteria) {
    return array.find(item => Object.keys(criteria).every(key => item[key] === criteria[key]))
}
```

Comment: You should add type to the arguments.  findWhere(array:Array, criteria:any){..}

Answer (score 0):

Does this Problem occur in all Browsers? As far as I know the IE11 does not suport the find function for arrays. Have a look at this: ["Object doesn't support property or method 'find'" in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788536/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-find-in-ie)

Also make sure that the array you are using is actually an array and not something else.